# windows 10 pro : open command window here

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-update, cmd.exe, context-menu

Windows 10 Pro with all updates

Not sure exactly when this started happening but I think it was with a Windows Update :

Windows Explorer > shift-right-click > "Open command window here" menu choice is no longer present.

I've searched web and don't find any realistic workarounds. There's some really old registry hacks that don't work anymore ( if they ever did ).

Is this intentional on Microsoft's part ?  Why ?  How to get it back ?

Comment: Yes; Use the Powershell option instead; there is an existing question with an answer with detail steps to restore the "command prompt" option

Comment: See this:: https://m.windowscentral.com/how-add-open-command-prompt-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560350